# Shortcode in separate php file

Tags: php, wordpress, modal-dialog, magnific-popup

I am trying to use shortcodes within a modal window. The code is inside of a separate php file. I am getting a Fatal error: Call to undefined function

This is the modal link which works fine:

```
<a class="model-link" href="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/location-modal.php">Location</a>
```

location-modal.php looks like this:

```
<div class="location-modal ">
  <h1 class="modal-title">Heading</h1>
  <p class="modal-para">test</p>
  <?php echo do_shortcode('[MYSHORTCODE]'); ?>
</div>
```

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick.

```
<?php
require('../../../wp-blog-header.php');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include your PHP file which contains the `do_shortcode` function. Do something like this:

```
<?php require_once "functions.php"; ?>
<div class="location-modal ">
  <h1 class="modal-title">Heading</h1>
  <p class="modal-para">test</p>
  <?php echo do_shortcode('[MYSHORTCODE]'); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Still getting Fatal error: Call to undefined function